# How to Stop Throttled Scroll from Propagating to Parent?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, throttling

I have Scrollable component that might have scrollable children or grand children. I want to throttle the `onScroll` handler in both components but also be able to prevent the child onScroll event from propagating to the parent.

My Attempts

---

```
import React from 'react;
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'

/*
This component stops the scroll from propagting to the parent
But does not throttle, calls handleScroll way too many times
*/
const UnthrottledSubPage = () => {
  const handleScroll = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.count(' SubPage: scrolled: ');
    console.log(event);
  };
  return (<div onScroll={handleScroll}>Sub Page</div>);
};
```

```
/*
This component throttles the scroll alright...but I have no way 
of stopping the scroll event from propagating to a scrollable parent
or grand parent.
*/
const ThrottledSubPageA = () => {
  const handleScroll = event => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // lineA: Called too late.
    console.count(' SubPage: scrolled: ');
    console.log(event);
  };
  return (<div onScroll={throttle(handleScroll, 1000)}>Sub Page</div>);
};
```

I "suspect", with this approach sometimes when `ThrottledSubPageA`s throttle is waiting, handleScroll is not called to stop the propagation and the parent scroll is called, or called when it was already pooled. Resulting to this warning.

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
>   you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `stopPropagation` on a
>   released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you
>   must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
>   See [React event-pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) for more information.

Runnable Snippet that reproduces this case. Open DevTools for the logs

```js
// Scrollable Component, called within a Scrollable Grand Parent (App).
const SubPage = () => {
  const handleScroll = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.count(' SubPage: scrolled: ');
    console.log(event);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="subpage"
      style={{ height: '200px' }}
      onScroll={throttle(handleScroll, 1000)}
    >
      <h1>Sub Page</h1>
      {/* Lengthy Scrollble Content */}
      <div className="content">Content</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const MainPage = props => {
  const { height } = props;
  return (
    <div className="page" style={{ height }}>
      <h1>Main Page</h1>
      <SubPage />
    </div>
  );
};

// Scrollable Component, that has a Scrollable Grand Child.
const App = () => {
  const handleScroll = event => {
    console.count(' App: scrolled: ');
    console.log(event);
  };

  return (
    <section className="app" onScroll={throttle(handleScroll, 1000)}>
      <MainPage height="200vh" />
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </section>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
/* Styles: Mostly Irrelevant to the question */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.app {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.page,
.subpage {
  background: aquamarine;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.subpage {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  height: 200vh;
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash.throttle@4.1.1/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
/*
This component doesn't throttle at all...and behaves like UnthrottledSubPage,
and whatever is within the throttle block is never called.
*/
const ThrottledSubPageB = () => {
  const handleScroll = event => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // lineA: Called alright.
    throttle(()=> {
      /* This block is never reached...*/
      console.count(' SubPage: scrolled: ');
      console.log(event);
    }, 1000);
  };
  return (<div onScroll={handleScroll)}>Sub Page</div>);
};
```

If I move the throttle to wrap the expensive scroll task, like `ThrottledSubPageB` above, the throttling never occurs! Again I "think"(I might be wrong) it might be because a new function is created on each scroll resulting to a new throttle, a new wait...which never comes. I cannot see it in the logs!

**Question:** , How can I make sure I call the throttle on scroll, but still stop the next scrolls within the wait, from propagating to the parent?